# Annotations as a substitute for Objects?

Tags: java, annotations

Recently I *tried* to implement a command line application using [Picocli](https://picocli.info/). This library uses annotations to define Commands, Options, etc.

I had never looked into annotations before and this library piqued my curiosity. Now that I am trying my own things, I cannot help but wonder: if I need an object to purely store data, would it be better to create a class, or to define an annotation?

Now, I understand that you need reflection to access the annotations at runtime, and that is very expensive. But say that you load them once and store them in memory; in a `Set<@Option>` for instance. Would they be more or less light way than a regular object?

For example:

```
@Target( { ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD} ) @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Option {

    String DEFAULT_STRING = "";

    String name();
    String description()    default DEFAULT_STRING;
    String [] params()      default {};

}
```

vs.

```
public class Option {

    private final String name;
    private String description;
    private String [] params;

    public Option(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Option (String name, String description, String [] params) {
        this(name);
        this.description = description;
        this.params = Arrays.copyOf(params, params.length);
    }

    // Getters & Setters

}
```

And then...

```
public class Foo {

    @Option(name = "var", description = "var description")
    private boolean var;

    public Foo() {
        Option option = new Option("var", "var description", new String[0]);
    }

}
```

Comment: You mentioned "_tried_ to implement a command line application using Picocli", which sounds like you did not succeed. Feel free to raise a ticket on the [picocli issue tracker](https://github.com/remkop/picocli/issues); I'd be happy to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An annotation will take slightly more memory than a custom class with normal fields. This is because the annotation is an interface, and Java will generate a `java.lang.reflect.Proxy` for each annotation instance with RUNTIME retention. The `AnnotationInvocationHandler` of that proxy stores the data values in a `LinkedHashMap`.

So there are a few more objects involved, and they take more space than with a normal class.